# How to get all alphanumeric strings in a range in c#?

Tags: c#

How do I get all alpha-number combo's in a given alpha-number combo range using c#?

For getting all numbers in a range I'll do something like below

```
int x = 10;
int y = 15;
int z=y-x+1;
var range =Enumerable.Range(x,z);
foreach (var element in range)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.ToString()+"-->"+x.ToString()+"-"+y.ToString());
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

But when the value of `x` is like `1x` and `y` is like `2b` how do I get the range of strings like below?

```
1x
1y
1z
2a
2b
```

Comment: x and y are ints, what do you mean by when they are 1x and 2b?

Comment: @FarazAhmad I mean if they are a combination of integer and alphabet, then how do I get the range ?

Comment: So there will always be a number and then ONE character?

Comment: yes, exactly...in each string, first will be a number then a single alphabet from a to z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, parse the string to get the numerical value and the character. Then, loop for each number from the start to the end. Inside, loop for each character in the alphabet from the start to the current end.

Here you go:

```
string x = "1x";
string y = "2b";

char startCharacter = x.Substring(x.Length-1)[0];
char endCharacter = y.Substring(y.Length-1)[0];
int startNumber = int.Parse(x.Substring(0, x.Length - 1));
int endNumber = int.Parse(y.Substring(0, y.Length - 1));

var range = new List<string>();
string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for(int i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; ++i) {
    int currentCharEnd = (i == endNumber) ? alphabet.IndexOf(endCharacter) : alphabet.Length - 1;
    for(int j = alphabet.IndexOf(startCharacter); j <= currentCharEnd; ++j) {
        range.Add(i.ToString() + alphabet[j]);
    }
    startCharacter = 'a';
}
// range is now { "1x", "1y", "1z", "2a", "2b" }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer....but can you explain it a little (specially the entire loop portion)?

Comment: Like I said: the outer loop goes from the start number (in this case '1') to the end number (in this case '2'). Inside, it goes from the start character (in the first run, it is (in this case) 'x', in all next runs it will be 'a') to the end character (in all runs except the last one it will be 'z', in the last run, it will be (in this case) 'b'). That's it.

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate the case where both 'x' and 'y' are integers in this code?

Comment: How can an integer have character values? Explain please.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by doing this, and extend it to achieve your task fully.

```
string[] abc = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };
string x = "1g";
string y = "2b";

string strx = Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value;
string stra = Regex.Match(x, @"[a-z]+").Value;
int intx = Int32.Parse(strx);

string stry = Regex.Match(y, @"\d+").Value;
string strb = Regex.Match(x, @"[a-z]+").Value;
int inty = Int32.Parse(stry);

Console.WriteLine(strx);
Console.WriteLine(stra);
Console.WriteLine("----");

int len = inty - intx + 1;
List<string> xycombinations = new List<string>();
string[] ycombinations = new string[] { };
if (len >= 0)
{
    int starting = 0;
    while (abc[starting] != stra)
    {
        starting = starting + 1;
    }
    while (starting < abc.Length)
    {
        xycombinations.Add(intx.ToString() + abc[starting]);
        starting = starting + 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < xycombinations.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xycombinations[i]);
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

It only makes the combination of string x till the end, for instance string x is `"1g"`, so this code makes combinations `1g, 1h, 1i, ij`. Similarly you can make combinations of `string y` by extending. Hope it helps you.